# Qt: Pass variables from ClassA to ClassB via Class C

Tags: c++, qt, share, qsettings

I have the following layout:

```
MainWindow  <--------- Settings
    \
     \
      V
   PerformOps
```

MainWindow takes in variables passed from Settings, and passes them on to PerformOps.
If the Settings class is not used, MainWindow passed on defaults to PerformOps.

Currently I do:

```
class Settings{

public: 
   Settings(*parent);
   var1, var2, var3
   .
   .
   void exec();
}

class PerformOps{

public: 
   PerformOps();
   var1, var2, var3;
   .
   .
   void start();
}


class MainWindow{

private:
  Settings *set;    //share pointers over all methods
  PerformOps *op;

  bool settings_not_clicked = false;

  void saveChanges()
  {
     QSettings settings("my","app");
     settings.setValue("value1", op->var1);
     settings.setValue("value2", op->var2);
     settings.setValue("value3", op->var3);
  }

  void loadChanges()
  {
     QSettings settings("my","app");
     op->var1 = settings.value("value1");
     op->var2 = settings.value("value2");
     op->var3 = settings.value("value3");

  }

  void closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event)
  {
       event->ignore();
       saveChanges();
       event->accept();
  }

  void takeDataAndDoStuff()   //This is always called
  {
     op = new PerformOps;

     if(settings_not_clicked) {
        loadChanges()
     }
     else {
         op->var1 = 33;
         op->var2 = "Geronimo!";
         op->var3 = true;              
     }

     op->start();
  }


  void getStuff_maybe_if_clicked()   //This might not be always called
  {
     Settings *set = new Settings(this);
     set->exec()      //Pause parent, run Settings

     settings_not_clicked = false;
  }
```

Question: Is there a cleaner way to share data across classes without resorting to the dirty method of : `op->var1 = set->var1;`, taking into account that the `set` pointer might not always be initialised?

Comment: Just wondering (irrelevant to the question), do you know about `QSettings` class?

Comment: I could not follow what is the issue.. Why do you call it "dirty"?

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall Yes, I'm actually using it -- it's the main source of my problems.

For example, when I'm saving my changes, I write all the values from the `set` pointer. But when reading in my changes, where do I read in to? Back to the set pointer? That's not allowed.

Comment: @RomanSaveljev Because I'm setting a pointer to a pointer that may or may not exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the approach itself is not that bad, however there are some things you can improve.

First of all, if I understood you correctly, you want to pass the settings if they exist, and pass the default values if they don't. In this case you can utilize the constructor:

```
class PerformOps
{
public:
    PerformOps( int v1 = 33, string v2 = "Geronimo!", bool v3 = true ): var1(v1), var2(v2), var3(v3)
    {
    }
    <...>
}
```

Now, if you call the constructor as `PerformOps()`, the default values will be set. If you call it and feed it some of the values, it will use them:

```
<...>
PerformOps *op;

if(settings_not_clicked) {
    op = new PerformOps( set->var1, set->var2, set->var3 );
}
else {
    op = new PerformOps();              
}
 <...>
```

of course, if you don't want to do it via the cunstructor, you could just make a function and call it like "setData()" and use the same technique with default function parameters.

---

Now, as for the pointers. It is a good idea to *always* initialize pointers with `NULL`, or `nullptr` if you have c++0x. Also, when you delete the memory, assign the pointer to `NULL` or `nullptr` again. This way you will be able to always see if the pointer is valid by a simple check.

```
someClass * ptr = nullptr;
<...>
ptr = new someClass();
<...>
delete ptr;
ptr = nullptr;
```

---

**UPD**

I would suggest you to get rid of your `Settings` class, and just use QSettings directly. You will not need to mess with the pointers, and reading/writing to QSettings is very fast.

Now, also don't forget that you can use QSettings from the heap:

```
QSettings * settings = new QSettings();
```

If you want each settings set to have a "parent", you could just derive your `Settings` class from `QSettings`, and just add one `parent` field into it. This will keep all the functionality of `QSettings`, which is very convenient.

Actually, your approach is fine too, all you need to do is just to check if the pointers are valid.

Comment: Okay let me edit my question -- I just realized its QSettings related

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the problem is "I'm setting a pointer to a pointer that may or may not exist". In such a case [Null Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) pattern should help. This way you should be able getting rid of if-clause

Answer (score 0):

Oh hang on.
I just realized that I can use QSettings between classes (which is what SingerOfTheFall was clearly hinting at)

So from my Settings.cpp class I can do:

```
QSettings sett("my");
sett.begingroup("my_groupname");
sett.setValue("value1", var1);
sett.setValue("value2", var2);
sett.setValue("value3", var3);
sett.endGroup();
```

and I can retrieve this same information from ANY CLASS (duh!) by doing:

someRandomClass.cpp:

```
QSettings settings("my");
settings.beginGroup("my_groupname");
myvar1 = settings.value("value1");
myvar2 = settings.value("value2");
myvar3 = settings.value("value3");
settings.endGroup();
```